# Change all the text boxes in a specific div to readonly using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change all the text boxes within a specific div to readonly and its not working.  Here is the code.

```
$("#bysuper").(function(){
        $('input[type=text]').prop('readonly',true);
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `$("#bysuper input[type=text]").prop("readonly", true);`

Comment: Please use same Quotes (Either single or double)in jQuery.The Quotes should be same for Starting and closing. $("   ') is not proper . Proper way:   $(" ")

Comment: Sorry, copy-pasted from original post.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer?

Comment: It's exactly the same as @PratikJoshi's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P27GU/)
Use following :

```
$("#bysuper input[type=text]").prop('readonly', true);
```

Means all inputs of type Textbox will have property as readonly.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the following to achieve your goal:

```
$("#bysuper").find(':text').prop('readonly',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

After much testing I settled on using find. But there was a couple big gotchas I found. 
I had to figure out that select and checkboxes had to be disabled and not set to readonly.  I assume this is somewhere in some documentation I missed.

I found that when using the datepicker within a input type text you had to also disable and not set to read only and since all my date fields had the class pickdate I found the class. This is my final code.

```
$(function(){
    $("#bysuper").find(':text,textarea').prop('readonly',true);
    $("#bysuper").find('select,:checkbox,.datepick').prop('disabled',true);    
})
```

Please feel free to correct my thinking on this subject as I am a neophyte.